# Suspicious visits to one URL from same user-agent but from unique IPs

Tags: firewalls, apache, mod-security, log-analysis, bot

For the past few weeks, I am observing a lots of visits from a specific user-agent - `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36` to one particular URL.

The user-agent corresponds to chrome 84 on windows 10 desktop. This browser is an old browser and the overall contribution to traffic is lesser than **1%**. But for the particular URL I am speaking about, **95%** of the traffic is from this user-agent. Bounce rate is **100%** for these visits. What is more confusing is that all the visits are from unique IPs and I couldn't find a pattern (like common location, revers DNS host, etc.,) in them.

I am clueless about where to start and how to proceed. Could this be a bot activity? If so, is there a way to find and prevent using firewalls like mod_security.

*P.S: I am using apache 2.4 server with mod_security and OWASP ruleset 3.3.*

Comment: `I am clueless about where to start and how to proceed`.  Why are these requests a problem?  When you run a public-facing web server, it will receive all kinds of bogus requests.  That's normal.  Trying to block these requests (or other illegitimate requests) is futile.  Just make sure that your server does not have a vulnerability that could be exploited by these requests (or others) and go on with your life.  Or, if you're really concerned, put your web server behind a WAF like Cloudflare.

Comment: OP, can you post a few of the IP addresses that these requests originated from?

Comment: Sure. Here are a few - 107.179.38.33, 185.242.111.71, 104.247.207.35, 208.202.230.240 and 156.248.82.183

Comment: The specific URL I am talking about is a resource-intensive one (relies on real-time data and has intensive DB queries) and due to the nature of the application, caching is not possible. Though the requests like the ones I mentioned have so far not overloaded the server, the requests are steadily increasing (now in the order of hundreds per day). Hence, they may cause concerns in the future if not checked.

Comment: It sounds like whoever/whatever is doing this may be trying to scrape your site to collect the data that your site provides.  They might be proxying their requests through a bot net so that they come from many different IP's instead of one.  Placing your site behind Cloudflare's web application firewall (WAF) will block most of these requests from reaching your server.  See https://www.cloudflare.com/waf/

Comment: Thanks. I will surely check the cloudflare firewall. But is there a way (like predefined ruleset) that I can use on mod_security? (I am already using mod_security with OWASP ruleset 3.3)

Comment: Thanks for providing more clarity on the problem, and why you feel that it's important to solve it.  These types of problems often turn into a cat-and-mouse game.  You could look for something unique to use as a condition to block these requests (such as the user agent), but they'll pickup on what you are doing, and change what they are doing, and it will just go on.  Cloudflare uses AI and ML to detect invalid requests and block them.  It's much more advanced than anything you can do with mod_security.  Their system is designed to play this cat-and-mouse game, and win.

Comment: Also, I checked the IPs that you posted to see if these are TOR exit nodes, or if these are on any lists of known abuse IP's, bot nets, etc.  If so, then maybe a solution to your problem could have been blacklisting IP's based on these lists.  But, these IPs are not on any of the lists that I checked.

Comment: Ok... I will seriously check the cloudflare WAF. If you can summarize the points you have mentioned as answer, I will mark it accepted.

Comment: Done.  Good luck.  https://www.netcials.com/ - nice site, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on conversation with OP in the comments following the question, [Cloudflare's web application firewall (WAF)](https://www.cloudflare.com/waf/) may be a solution.  See comments for more information as to why OP feels that this problem needs to be addressed, why this problem may be difficult for him to solve on his own using mod_security, and how Cloudflare's WAF may be a more effective solution.